# Cannot get get_queried_object() from a function called in archive.php

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy-terms

I wrote an "autocomplete" field in archive.php - typing in it calls a function defined in functions.php. Here is a sample of the code:

```
function ajax_search_archive() {
$term = get_queried_object();
if (!$term) return;

(... continued...)
}
```

I tried that in a "tag" archive page, then in a "category" archive page. Each time, the function was called, then returned 0 at the second line because the retrieved "get_queried_object" was null - though I expected it wasn't.

Please, what did I wrong?

Comment: You sure it goes into the function? Wordpress ajax always return 0 even when no function is called. echo "here"; before term. You should see it in the return.

Comment: I did that, so I'm positive about the function being called.

Comment: ok try print_r($term); what does that return? and what does print_r($_REQUEST); return?

Comment: Where should I use print_r? Since the function is called through Ajax, I use "echo json_encode()".
echo json_encode($term) returns null.
echo json_encode($_REQUEST) returns the arguments of the call: e.g. {"action":"get_archived_posts","name":"King"}

Comment: Solved! Thanks for your advice which showed me the way! The function get_queried_object() seems to work when called in archive.php itself, but not when called in another file (even inside a function called in archive.php). So I updated a) the archive.php file to retrieve the get_queried_object() and store its id into a hidden field, b) the Ajax call, to send the object id as another argument, and c) the function ajax_search_archive, to retrieve the object id from the POST request.

Comment: Maybe I should post the previous comment as an answer to my own question... ?

Comment: Don't know the rules for that haha ;) maybe you can edit your own post

Comment: Yeah, you should!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks again for the comments, which showed me the way to solve my own problem.

The function get_queried_object() seems to work when called in archive.php itself, but *not* when called from a function defined in another file - even if that other function is called in archive.php. That realization led me to do some updates:

a) in archive.php: retrieving the get_queried_object(), storing its id into a hidden field (e.g. "archive_id)";

b) the Ajax "autocomplete" call in its script: sending the object id as another argument (value retrieved using jQuery - e.g. "$('#archive_id').val()");

c) the function ajax_search_archive in functions.php: retrieving the object id from the POST request.